# Symfony error handling duplicate entry

Tags: symfony, duplicates

When I fill in a duplicate entry in my symfony database and click submit I get an error duplicate entry. (As intended) But I need something to check this before submitting, but I have no clue where to start searching for a solution.

Comment: How do you know it's a duplicate entry? Can you provide more information?

Comment: give me your feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this data come from a form? If so, maybe you could check out http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html. This adds a unique validation based on fields you provide. If you don't use a form you could still use the validator separately to validate your object.

Comment: It comes from an Entity, but I need to fill this in in an form yes. I will have look at your link, thank you!